# One extra character counted in basic compression algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on building a basic compression algorithm based on the questions from Cracking the Code Interview Version 5:

> Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts of
>       repeated characters. For example, the string aabcccccaaa would become
>       a2blc5a3. If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original
>       string, your method should return the original string.

This is my algorithm:

```
public static String compress(String str) {
    StringBuffer comp = new StringBuffer();
    int count = 1;

    char currentChar = str.charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(currentChar == str.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            comp.append(currentChar);
            comp.append(count);
            count = 1;
            currentChar = str.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(currentChar);
        }
    }

    comp.append(currentChar);
    comp.append(count);

    return comp.toString();
}
```

When I run this algorithm with the following input:

```
System.out.println(compress("aaabcdef"));
```

I get the following output:

```
b
c
d
e
f
a4b1c1d1e1f1
```

Specifically, the `a` is counted one extra. Why is that?

Comment: Don't forget to check for `str.length() <= comp.length()`, and return the shorter one.  Apparently omitting the count isn't allowed, even when it's one, for some reason.  This compression scheme is still ambiguous if the input string contained digits, unless the counts limited to single-digit.  If no, the decoder has to look for the first non-digit character.  So either the counts have to be kept to a single character, or the coding scheme should allow `a3bcdef` since only non-digits would be allowable in input strings.

Comment: If you're going to use single-character run-lengths, it'd be more efficient if they were binary rather than strings.  So the range would be 1-255 (or 1-65535), rather than 1-9.  Decoding would skip the string-to-int step.  Actually, 1-127 would avoid headaches for UTF8, and in Java's UTF16 you'd have to avoid creating start-of-a-two-char surrogate pair chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
     for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

to

```
     for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
```

You already counted the first character at this line:

```
    char currentChar = str.charAt(0);
```

So you want to start from the second character in the string.

Comment: Oohhh! That's why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change `int count = 1;` to `int count = 0;`
That would fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
```

And a suggestion, avoid printing number "1" for letters that occurs just once, you're saving more space in this way: change

```
comp.append(count);
```

to

```
comp.append(count==1?"":count);
```

your string is even more compressed and still lossless:

```
a4bcdef
```